# I want buttons to be displayed once, not twice

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons which are both displayed twice like below:

```
Button 1 (Performs the onclick='SelectAll(this)')
Button 1 (Performs the onclick='RemoveAll(this)')

Button 2 (Performs the onclick='SelectAll(this)')
Button 2 (Performs the onclick='RemoveAll(this)')
```

Both Button 1 and Button 2 should appear once like below:

```
Button 1 (Performs the onclick='SelectAll(this)')
Button 2 (Performs the onclick='RemoveAll(this)')
```

How can I achieve this above:

The code which displays these buttons are below:

```
function insertButton(form) {   


var $answer = $("<table class='answer'></table>");

$('.buttonOne:first, .buttonTwo:first').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $BtnsClass = '';

        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);


        $BtnsClass = $("<input class='buttonOne btnsAll' type='button' style='display: block;' value='Button 1' onClick='selectAll(this);' />
        <br/>
        <input class='buttonTwo btnsRemove' type='button' style='display: block;' value='Button 2' onClick='removeAll(this);' />")
        .attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));

        $BtnsClass.appendTo($cell);

    });  

        $tr.append($answer);

        }
```

Below is the html where the buttons in the jquery should match to

```
<p><input class="buttonOne btnsAll" name="allBtnsName" type="button" value="Button 1" onClick="selectAll(this);" />
<br/><input class="buttonTwo btnsRemove" name="allRemoveBtnsName" type="button" value="Button 2" onClick="removeAll(this);" /></p>
```

The html buttons only display each button once which is fine, so why is the jquery displaying the buttons twice and not once?

Comment: Tried removing the loop?

Comment: What you like to achieve? Your code is confusing.

Comment: like I said on top it should display Button 1 only once and Button 2 only once. At the moment it is displaying them both twice

Comment: What is the html that starts on the page, how do you want it to behave, and what do you want the end result to be? The code you provided doesn't make any button functionality it says "when I run this function find buttons which are already on the page, for each button you find (that selector could return up to 2 things) stick some stuff on the page". Is this what you intended?

Comment: ok give me 5 mins to put some more code in the page. In the mean time how do I create a normal function rather than a .each function for  the code above?

Comment: You have to select your button-filling-fields sololy. like $('buttonOne:first').append(...); $('buttonTwo').append(...);

Comment: Html code is now in question, I have mention on top of question how I want the buttons to be displayed and the onclick events they should match

Comment: @Tai Kahar can you show me an example of this in an answer? If you do this then I can see what you mean and I can mark your answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for some functionality like below,

```
function insertButton(form) {   

    var $answer = $("<table class='answer'></table>");

    var $btnOne = $('.buttonOne:first');
    var $btnTwo = $('.buttonTwo:first');

    var $BtnsClass = '';

    $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
    $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);

    $BtnsClass = $("<input class='buttonOne btnsAll' type='button' style='display: block;' value='Button 1' onClick='selectAll(this);' />
        <br/>
        <input class='buttonTwo btnsRemove' type='button' style='display: block;' value='Button 2' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");

    $BtnsClass.attr('name', $btnOne.attr('name')).attr('value', $btnOne.val()).attr('class', $btnOne.attr('class')).appendTo($cell);

    $BtnsClass.attr('name', $btnTwo.attr('name')).attr('value', $btnTwo.val()).attr('class', $btnTwo.attr('class')).appendTo($cell);

    $tr.append($answer);
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't fixed yet but I will try and manipulate this code and try and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you've got there in your code is a conversion function.  It's taking the first instance of `.buttonOne` and the first instance of `.buttonTwo` and inserting two `input type="button"` tags *for each one*.  Based on your code example, you're probably seeing is this as the output:

```
Button 1
Button 2

Button 1
Button 2
```

If that's the case, then you have some options to get it down to just one instance of each button.  The simplest would be to remove the `.buttonTwo:first` from the selector where you activate the `each` call.  This will make it convert only the first instance of `.buttonOne` into the two `input` tags.

Another option would be to split the `each` method into two separate calls - one for `.buttonOne:first` and one for `.buttonTwo:first` - so that the action only creates a single `input` tag for each matching element.  You'd also need to modify the code to only insert a single `input` tag rather than the two tags that it's doing now.

A third option would be to make the code in the `each` function smart enough to look at the `$this` object and get the correct button CSS class (`buttonOne` or `buttonTwo`) and then create the correct `input` tag based on that class.  That could require a bit of work to rewrite the code you have to give it that intelligence, but you'd end up with a more streamlined approach.

You could try something like the following (NOTE:  **UNTESTED**):

```
    function insertButton(form) {
    var $answer = $("<table class='answer'></table>");

    $('.buttonOne:first, .buttonTwo:first').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $BtnsClass, clickEvent = '';

        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);

        if ($this.hasClass('buttonOne')) {
            clickEvent = 'selectAll(this);';
        }
        else if ($this.hasClass('buttonTwo')) {
            clickEvent = 'removeAll(this);';
        }

        $BtnsClass = $("<input type='button' style='display: block;' onClick='" + clickEvent + "' />")
                .attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
        $BtnsClass.appendTo($cell);
        });

    $tr.append($answer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The each function is triggering twice because it triggers once per selector... Even the selector doesn't look right.

```
function insertButton(form)
{
     var btn1 = $(document.createElement('button'));
         btn1.attr("name" somename);

     var btn2 = $(document.createElement('button'));
         btn2.attr("name" somename);

     $(form).append(btn1).append(btn2);
}
```

Your code is super confusing, but i think this is what you want? Or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.template Plugin](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rGe4/1/